# Check for nil with guard instead of if?

Tags: swift

Is there a `guard` equivalent of checking if a variable is `nil`? If so how would I translate a statement like this to use `guard` instead?

```
if post["preview"]! != nil {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //handle case where the variable is nil
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Like some people already answered, you can use `let`

```
guard let preview = post["preview"] else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

If you are not using the variable, you can use an underscore to not declare the variable and avoid the warning.

```
guard let _ = post["preview"] else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

You can also do a regular boolean check instead of using `let`

```
guard post["preview"] != nil else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

A more general case for a boolean check on a `guard`

```
guard conditionYouExpectToBeTrue else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

If you want to be able to modify the variable, you can use `var` instead of `let`

```
guard var preview = post["preview"] else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

**Swift 3.0**

You can combine `var/let` with a boolean check by using commas between the statements.

```
guard let preview = post["preview"], preview != "No Preview" else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

**Swift 2.x**

You can combine `var/let` with the boolean check by using where `where`

```
guard let preview = post["preview"] where preview != "No Preview" else { /* Handle nil case */ return }
```

Comment: I tried just doing a nil check with guard and got a weird result (see edit). Any idea why?

Comment: Why are you unwrapping it twice?

Comment: I'm dealing with JSON that for some reason only seems to give me data after I unwrap it twice.

Comment: What about `guard case nil = post["preview"] else {}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use guard to grab the value from the `post` dictionary:

```
guard let value = post["preview"] else {
    return  // or break, or throw, or fatalError, etc.
}
// continue using `value`
```

Comment: When I do anything like this, post["preview"] behaves differently afterwards (see edit). Do you know what's up?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want a `guard-let` construction, like this:

```
guard let preview = post["preview"] else { */ nil case */ }

/* handle non-nil case here... preview is non-nil */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use guards with `let`.

```
guard let preview = post["preview"] else {
   //handle case where the variable is nil
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants a `guard` statement