# Handling Null ref from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-swift

I have an application where I am using Firebase and RxSwift. I am getting snapshot from a ref and the issue I have now is the ref could be null i.e it does not exist. how do I still make my code run to by pass the null reason

if Null, I should call onCompleted.

```
func refreshActiveTrip() -> Observable<Trip> {

        guard let trip = getCurrentTrip()  else {
            return Observable.error(RxError.noElements)
        }

        tripRef = Database.database().reference(forTransportChampionId: (getChampion()?.id)!, tripId: trip.id!)
        return Observable<Trip>.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in

            let disposable = Disposables.create {
                self.tripRef?.removeAllObservers()
            }

            self.tripRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists(){

                    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                        let trip = Trip(dictionary: data as NSDictionary)
                        print("SPLASH TRIP CURRENT \(data)")

                        self.saveCurrentTrip(trip)
                        observer.onNext(trip)
                        observer.onCompleted()

                    }
                    print("It exists!!")
                }else{
                    let trip = Trip()
                    self.saveCurrentTrip(trip)
                    print("Nope, doesn't exist!")
                }
            })

            return disposable
        })

    }
```

the `tripRef` could be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already creating an Observable with `Observable.create()`, you can simply call `observer.onCompleted()` in your else clause.

That said, it seems to me that you should be emitting the `Trip()` object that you created instead and then saving it outside this function.

---

More information:

For what you are doing, would expect something more like this:

```
func refreshActiveTrip(_ trip: Trip?, championId: String) -> Observable<Trip> {
    guard let trip = trip else { return Observable.error(RxError.noElements) }
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let tripRef = Database.database().reference(forTransportChampionId: championId, tripId: trip.id!)
        tripRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            var trip = Trip()
            if snapshot.exists(), let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                trip = Trip(dictionary: data as NSDictionary)
            }
            observer.onNext(trip)
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        return Disposables.create { tripRef.removeAllObservers() }
    }
}
```

Note that the above is a *free function*; it is not inside any class.

To fully realize the code you have, it would be used like this:

```
refreshActiveTrip(getCurrentTrip(), championId: getChampion()!.id!)
    .do(onNext: { [weak self] trip in self?.saveCurrentTrip(trip) })
    .filter { $0.id != nil }
```

Presumably, the above would be in a flatMap that catches errors...

Lastly, you should consider using [RxFirebase](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxFirebase)

Comment: how would RXFirebase help address this?

Comment: `Result of call to 'filter' is unused` I want to be able to call a function like `refreshActiveTrip()
            .do(onNext: { [weak self] trip in
                self?.source.saveCurrentTrip(trip)
                showHomePage()
            })
            .filter { $0.id != nil }` the showHomePage()

Comment: That's the same warning you would get if you called your origional `refreshActiveTrip()` and is solved the same way. Remember, Observables don't do anything unless you subscribe to them.

Comment: RxFirebase already has all the reactive wrappers around the Database object and calls like `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` so you don't have to implement them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guard let for prevent this nil situation.

Check this out,

[Check for nil with guard instead of if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341485/check-for-nil-with-guard-instead-of-if)